# Asynchronously streaming a file system text file using jQuery (MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

A text file exists on my server machine which is constantly being updated (about once about 5 seconds). On my web page, I'd like a div to display this file live using jQuery inside MVC.

I have the [jQuery timer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) working already, but the file isn't displaying. My plan was to get the jQuery to load a Controller Action every 5 seconds and have this action return a FilePathResult.

The script:

```
$(function () {
        var streamer = $("div.wrapper div.streamer");
        //===

        var active = false;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".uncontrolled-interval p", streamer).everyTime(1000, function () {
                $(this).load("/Home/Stream");
            });
        });
    });
```

The view:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="streamer">
        <div  id="uncontrolled-interval" style=" height:420px; width:1200px; background-color:Black; color:White;  overflow: auto; " ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
 Public Function Stream() As ActionResult
    Return File(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("LiveStreamPath"), "text/plain")
End Function
```

`LiveStreamPath` contains the path to the text file. I was thinking of creating a StreamReader in the Action instead. What sorts of implementations can I use to get this file to stream?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches: POLL and PUSH.

The one you have adopted is having the client polling the server at regular intervals by sending AJAX requests and showing the results even if the contents hasn't changed. In this scenario you have a shared resource. This shared resource is the file. This resource could be concurrently accessed by different threads/processes. The problem with files is that while one thread is writing to the file (you said the file is getting updated every 5 seconds), if another thread tries to read from it, it is very likely to either fail or get inconsistent data from the file. So if you decide to go with the polling approach you must ensure that you synchronize access to this file properly. Depending on whether it is another thread that it is writing to the file or another process there might be different techniques to achieve this. For example if it is another thread you could use a [Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) (equivalent to C# `lock`). For cross process synchronization of shared resources you could use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

The second approach is the PUSH approach. In this model it is the server which sends notification to clients when the file gets updated. It is a far more optimized since clients are not hamerring the server with lots of AJAX requests. There are different techniques to implement this. For example in HTML5 you could use WebSockets. Microsoft are working on a great platform called [Signalr](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) which enables this scenario in a very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for the jquery for a little test app (testing the background, not making the foreground work beautifully. It is called by clicking a link, which sends 1 request to start the process and fires off the monitor.

```
function startJob() {
    $.get('<%=ResolveUrl("~/Background/StartJob.ashx") %>');
    setTimeout('updateStatus()', 500);
}
function updateStatus() {
    $("#results").load('<%=ResolveUrl("~/Background/ReadStatus.ashx") %>');
    setTimeout('updateStatus()', 500);
}
```

In the background, you can use the [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) to do this simply, while not opening a lock on anything.

For writing you can use [File.AppendText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) / `AppendBytes()` etc, which will append to the file without putting a read lock on it.  Only rarely have I used the streamwriter and all the FileShare parameters, this is generally enough for a web app.

Yes, if you are updating constantly, and with large amounts of data, you may get inconsistent reads.  If that isn't a problem (eg, no heavy processing, the ui doesn't care much), then leave it as is.  If the UI does care, then use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

> Represents a lock that is used to manage access to a resource, allowing multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing.